# One-line async method SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, winforms, deadlock, synchronizationcontext

I prepared WinForms application to test if a one-line async method would cause a deadlock. `button1_Click` event waits for `GetZero` task awaited by one-line async proxy method. However, it causes deadlock. Why? I've read that one-line async method do not need to continue anything after `await` completes, so there is no delegate to post to message pump causing deadlock.

For reference, `button2_Click` event waits for the result of task `GetZero` without proxy caller, and application works fine.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var zero = ProxyCallery().Result;
        label1.Text += $"{zero}";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var zero = GetZero().Result;
        label1.Text += $"{zero}";
    }

    private async Task<int> ProxyCallery()
    {
        return await GetZero();
    }

    private async Task<int> GetZero()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Why is `button1_Click` causing deadlock?

Comment: Try calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the await expression in `ProxyCallery`. I vaguely remember that the `ConfigureAwait`s must be consistent along the call chain.

Comment: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). See the part `Preventing the Deadlock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);` configures the await only for that call. It doesn't affect awaits that might depend on that particular one, such as the `await GetZero()` in the `ProxyCallery()` method.

That latter await is still going to require continuation in the UI thread, which you've blocked with `ProxyCallery().Result`. Hence the deadlock.

> I've read that one-line async method do not need to continue anything after await completes, so there is no delegate to post to message pump causing deadlock.

I don't know where you've read that, but it's false. The compiler doesn't try to optimize "tail awaits". In reality, even if the last thing in the method is an `await`, there is still code to be executed on the continuation. At the very least, unwrapping any exception, but also propagating the continuation to the `Task` represented by that `async` method.

So there is no difference at all with respect to deadlock potential, or any other aspect of asynchronous execution, for `await` statements that conclude a method as compared to `await` statements found anywhere else in a method.

Comment: so why it's not necessary to ConfigureAwait(false) a second await in GetZero method? `return await Task.FromResult(0);` From what you've said this await also needs continuation in the same synchronization context, so why it doesn't cause deadlock?

Comment: Because that await doesn't occur until _after_ the previous, configured await has completed. This is different from the await you're asking about, in `ProxyCallery()`, which happens _before_ that previous, configured await has _completed_. What matters is the sync context you're in _at the time of the await_, not at the time of the initiation of the thing being awaited. Since the configured await hasn't "come back" yet, the sync context is still whatever it was when the async method yielded in the first place. In this case, that's the UI thread.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - `return await Task.FromResult(0);` doesn't cause a deadlock because it is started from a different context than 'UI thread' because of ConfigureAwait of previous task? Specifically, it is started in context of that prevoius `await`?

Comment: _"`return await Task.FromResult(0);` doesn't cause a deadlock because it is started from a different context"_ -- yes, but mostly no. If the task were a true asynchronous task, your reasoning would be correct. However, `Task.FromResult(0)` returns an already-completed task, and so that particular `await` completes synchronously. I.e. it returns immediately without yielding the thread and so it doesn't matter what the thread would have been doing had it yielded, no deadlock could occur.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProxyCallery` is actually two lines, in the sense that there *is* a continuation after the async operation:

```
private async Task<int> ProxyCallery()
{
    var zero = await GetZero();
    return zero; // <-- continuation!
}
```

The continuation is to *return the task's result*!

Currently, the above continuation is not in the same synchronisation context as the continuation to the `Task.Delay` task, which is what causes the deadlock.

Every task you create should be in the same synchronisation context!

```
private async Task<int> ProxyCallery()
{
    var zero = await GetZero().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return zero;
}
```